# Draw dotted lines using Quartz on iPhone

Tags: iphone, drawing, quartz-graphics, dotted-line

I am developing an application in which I need to draw dotted lines between a couple of points. I tried

```
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound)
CGContextSetLineDash(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, lengths, LENGTH_OF_ARRAY)
```

But I see dashed lines instead of dotted lines. How can I get dotted lines instead?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html

Comment: This is an old post, but the above comment doesn't actually help. That link doesn't cover drawing dots.

Comment: Sure it does. There's a whole section on "Painting a Path" where it describes how to draw a "line dash pattern" using CGContextSetLineDash https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGContextSetLineDash

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat lengths[2];
lengths[0] = 0;
lengths[1] = dotRadius * 2;
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, dotRadius);
CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0.0f, lengths, 2);

// CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, self.bounds);
```

This code should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please, see the following great page about the roles of line properties!
https://horseshoe7.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/core-graphics-line-drawing-explained/

According to the above page, here is the code for the 'dot' line like ( . . . .)

```
// should
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

// please see the role of line properties why the first should be 0 and the second should be the doulbe of the given line width
CGFloat dash[] = {0, lineWidth*2};

// the second value (0) means the span between sets of dot patterns defined by dash array
CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, dash, 2);
```